# Assign values in groups of three - pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, ceil

I am trying to `assign` `unique` values from a `pandas` `df` in groups of `3`. For the `df` below I have a `Column` of values that appear a number of times. I calculate how many of these values are *currently occurring*. That is, if they appear again they are considered to be *on*.

**If a new value appears it increases the number of values that are on. If a value doesn't appear again it decrease the number of values that are on.**

This is my attempt below. I can get it to group in three's. But it doesn't consider the `unique` values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = ({             
   'Place' : ['House 1','House 2','House 3','House 4','House 1','House 2','House 3','House 4'],#,'House 1','House 2']#,'House 4','House 5','House 6','House 7'],                                                                        
   'On' : [1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1],                                                               
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df["Ind"] = np.ceil(df["On"]/3)

Output:

     Place  On    P
0  House 1   1  1.0
1  House 2   2  1.0
2  House 3   3  1.0
3  House 4   4  2.0
4  House 1   4  2.0
5  House 2   3  1.0
6  House 3   2  1.0
7  House 4   1  1.0
```

Intended Output:

```
     Place  On    P
0  House 1   1  1.0
1  House 2   2  1.0
2  House 3   3  1.0
3  House 4   4  2.0
4  House 1   4  1.0
5  House 2   3  1.0
6  House 3   2  1.0
7  House 4   1  1.0
```

Description:

The difference is in `Index 4`. `Houses 1` should be assigned to `1` as they were originally assigned to this `integer`.

Description for `On` Column:

```
Index 0: House 1 is inserted and it appears again = 1 
Index 1: House 2 is inserted and it appears again = 2 
Index 2: House 3 is inserted and it appears again = 3 
Index 3: House 4 is inserted and it appears again = 4 
Index 4: House 1 doesn't appear again so it will decrease number of values on on the next row = 4 
Index 5: House 2 doesn't appear again so it will decrease number of values on  = 3 
Index 6: House 3 doesn't appear again so it will decrease number of values on  = 2 
Index 7: House 4 doesn't appear again so it will decrease number of values on  = 1
```

Comment: Could you explain the logic here a bit more? I've re-read several times and am still unsure. Is the `On` column supposed to track how many unique `Place`s occur in groups of 3, how can its value exceed 3?

Comment: Thanks @PeterLeimbigler. It explains how many values are occuring in `Place`. So it's not how many unique values occur in total. It's how many unique values are happening. Does that make sense. I'll add more detail into the description